# Elastic Beanstalk Custom CloudWatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an Elastic Beanstalk Environment on AWS where I deploy via Docker container. I've enabled the default logs from the UI Configuration of Beanstalk and we get standard logs such as eb-activity.log in CloudWatch.

My goal is to integrate the custom logfile: **logger.log into CloudWatch.**

**Dockerrun.aws.json** looks like this:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "3000"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/path/to/logs"
}
```

Then in **.ebextensions/01_cloudwatch.config** I have

```
files:
  /etc/awslogs/config/my_app_log.conf: 
    content: |
        [/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/logger.log]
        log_group_name=/aws/elasticbeanstalk/appname/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/logger.log
        log_stream_name={instance_id}
        file=/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/logger.log
    group: root
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
```

The **eb-user** has full permissions of CloudWatch (CloudWatchFullAccess and CloudWatchLogsFullAccess). Also, I can validate the existence of **/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/logger.log**.

Still, logs don't appear in CloudWatch. In the same directory there are afc818177506-stdouterr.log files that appear in CloudWatch, they're being configured in /etc/awslogs/config/beanstalklogs.conf. Moreover, I made sure to do *sudo service awslogs restart*.

Any idea how to debug the problem or do you see any obvious mistake I did so logger.log does not appear in CloudWatch? Many thanks!

PS. I've already looked at the similar questions and have tried a good amount of time to solve the issue without success, so your help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cloudwatch agent FAQ at the bottom of [this reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html), these are common reasons log events are not sent:

1. size of log event is > 256K
2. timestamp of log entries is off (>2 hours in future or >2 weeks in past) - perhaps clear your log file if you have a stale logger.log
3. log events older than the retention period
4. large log batches spanning more than 24hr

Lastly - to troubleshoot why cloudwatch log agent might be failing, check
`/var/log/awslogs.log`
and to troubleshoot the agent was installed correctly on the EC2 instance, check `/var/log/awslogs-agent-setup.log`

See if any of these tips help, and post back if you are still stuck with more information and we will continue to try and help you.